# How to force bash/zsh to evaluate parameter as multiple arguments when applied to a command

Tags: command, zsh, arguments, expansion

I am trying to run a program like this:

```
$CMD $ARGS
```

where $ARGS is a set of arguments with spaces.  However, zsh appears to be handing off the contents of $ARGS as a single argument to the executable.  Here is a specific example:

```
$export ARGS="localhost -p22"
$ssh $ARGS
ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost -p22: Name or service not known
```

Is there a bash or zsh flag that controls this behavior?

Note that when I put this type of command in a $!/bin/sh script, it performs as expected.

Thanks,

SetJmp

Comment: Doesn't it mean zsh is not POSIX-compliant?

Comment: @jpalecek It is not unless explicitely requested (by setting some options, by calling it using `**/sh` -> `/bin/zsh` symlink or by using `emulate sh` (which in turn just sets some options)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will work if you use `eval $CMD $ARGS`.

Answer (score 23):

In zsh it's easy:

Use `cmd ${=ARGS}` to split `$ARGS` into separate arguments by word (split on whitespace).

Use `cmd ${(f)ARGS}` to split `$ARGS` into separate arguments by line (split on newlines but not spaces/tabs).

As others have mentioned, setting SH_WORD_SPLIT makes word splitting happen by default, but before you do that in zsh, cf. http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html for an explanation as to why whitespace splitting is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have a string variable (there are also arrays) be split into words before passing to a command, use `$=VAR`. There is also an option (`shwordsplit` if I am not mistaking) that will make any `command $VAR` act like `command $=VAR`, but I suggest not to set it: I find it very inconvenient to type things like `command "$VAR"` (zsh: `command $VAR`) and `command "${ARRAY[@]}"` (zsh: `command $ARRAY`).